# I'm trying to understand Optionals in Swift. Code works, but I don't understand why

Tags: swift, option-type

I'm working on a task at Excercism and have been doing online swift courses for a while. I completed a task and saw this solution (which was much less code than mine). Why is this an optional?

I don't understand what is the purpose of the underscore at the beginning of the function before the X and why deleting it breaks the code. I also am confused why it works with only one input parameter even the there are X and Y required in the function. Further, adding "Alice" for X and "Steve" for Y doesn't work unless I add a label, but works for X without a label.

```
import UIKit

func TwoFer(_ X: String = "you ", Y: String = "one for me") -> String {
    return "one for \(X) " + "\(Y)"
}

TwoFer() // Prints one for you, one for me

TwoFer("Alice")  //Prints one for Alice, one for me

TwoFer("Alice", "Steve")  // ERROR: Missing argument label for Y:
```

The expected result was that it wouldn't work as there is no question mark turning X into an optional.

Comment: There are no optionals in this code, you are using default parameters: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID169

Comment: Thank you Vadian for clear that out for me. That does explain why I'm able to change the default setting. However, what is the purpose of the underscore(_ here and why does the second default parameter require a label if I want to change that one as well?

Answer (score 4):

The question is not related to Optionals (in terms of Swift) at all.

- Parameters with default values can be omitted in the function call regardless if the parameter label has to be specified or not.
- The underscore means *omit the (external) parameter label* in the function call. The first label is omitted the second is not.

You have to write

```
TwoFer("Alice", Y:"Steve")
```

If you want to omit the second label, too – which is not recommended by the way – you have to declare the function

```
func TwoFer(_ X: String = "you ", _ Y: String = "one for me") -> String
```

---

Note:

According to the naming convention functions, variables and parameter labels should be named with starting lowercase letter.

```
func twoFer(_ x: String = "you ", _ y: String = "one for me") -> String
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Vadian. That clears a fair amount of confusion. I will re-read on the subject and keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

- Both `X` and `Y` have default values, which is why you can call the method with no arguments.
- The underscore `_` on the first argument means that it has no label when called externally, but is referred to internally as `X`. `Y` is referred to both internally and externally as `Y`, which is why it needs to be explicitly provided.

```swift
TwoFer() // Uses the default values for X and Y
TwoFer("Alice") // "Alice" is X but does not require a label due to the underscore (`_`)
TwoFer("Alice", "Steve") // ERROR: Missing argument label for Y, as you pointed out
TwoFer("Alice", Y: "one for Steve") // "Alice" is X, "one for Steve" is Y
```

The [Swift Documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html) has more on this.

> The print(_:separator:terminator:) function doesn’t have a label for its first argument, and its other arguments are optional because they have a default value. These variations on function syntax are discussed below in Function Argument Labels and Parameter Names and Default Parameter Values.
>   https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html

Answer (score 1):

*Just to start this off - there are **no** Optionals in this code. Optionals are denoted using `?` and `!`. Side note - functions should follow [Camel Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) for readability in Swift.*

## Purpose of the underscore

Consider your function:

```
func twoFer(_ x: String = "you ", y: String = "one for me") -> String {
    return "one for \(x) " + "\(y)"
}
```

Called like so:

```
twoFer("Alice", y: "Steve")
```

An underscore - just like in other places in Swift - ignore the value, or in this case, the parameter label. The documentation can all be found here for your issues, under [Function Argument Labels and Parameter Names](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID166).

## Parameter labels

Alternatively, your function (secretly) looks like this - notice the double y:

```
func twoFer(_ x: String = "you ", y y: String = "one for me") -> String {
    return "one for \(x) " + "\(y)"
}
```

*The `y` parameter name does not need to be shown - it could be simplified to a single `y`, but as I said, this is what it "secretly" looks like.*

In which case you would call the function as follows:

```
twoFer("Alice", y: "Steve")
```

## How does a single parameter work?

You created a parameter with a **default value**, shown by the `=`, like `x: String = "you "` - and it would look like `x: String` if you had no default value. Default values just get rid of unnecessary parameters.

## Why does `y` not work when initialised?

Well, quite simply, you only set up the parameter name for `x`. Set it up for `y` as follows with the underscore:

```
_ y: String = "one for me"
```